# Update a single attribute via a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update a single attribute via a link (click "set as default account", which sets the is_default column to true). I have the following link:

```
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
.
.
  <%= link_to 'Set as default', account, method: :put %>
```

... as you can see I'm using "account" object to set the URL. This results in something like `"/accounts/7"`. But, I don't know how to pass the is_default=true param. Should I do something different here? Should I use a *_path? Also I'm guessing I want an address such as `"/accounts/7?is_default=true"` (or `"/accounts/7/setdefault"` and configure the controller and routes.rb to handle this?)

How do I pass a param in a string in this case? Also, what is the best practise? I've looked in other questions but can't quite find something specific to this, then again I am a newbie :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, for example

```
<%= link_to 'Set as default', account_path(account, is_default: true), method: :put %>
```

Documentation: [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to 'Set as default',{:controller => "" ,:action=>"" ,:id => ,:is_default=>true} %>
```